# No desktop, only tty, sudo startx doesn't work

Tags: command-line, gdm, tty

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

The problem is I have no GUI, stuck in tty...

I can't run `apt-get update` and there is no internet in tty.

When I run `sudo startx` it is showing this:

```
marker: (--) probd, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(**) from command line, (!!) notice, (!!) international,
(ww) warning,(EE) error, (NI) Not implemented, (??) unknown.

(==) logfile: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" , Time: Fri jun 5 
(==) Using system config directory "/var/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
waiting for X server to shutdown(II) server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.r lost
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you recently install Ubuntu? If so, try reinstalling Ubuntu Desktop and see if your issue persists

Comment: no, i didnt install recently.

Comment: check the log at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" and post it to paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: The problem is how to copy that log file? As I have access to only tty . and no internet in tty